# data analysis EDA issues, indent or type

Tags: dataset, data-cleaning, data-analysis

I am a newbie in DS world, right now i am working on some EDA practice, and run into an issue here.

Here is my code:

---

### Convert some columns to numeric values

```
for column in cols:
    auto[column] = pd.to_numeric(auto[column] 
    return auto

auto = read_auto_data()
```

---

1. error 1:
   File "", line 4
   return auto
   ^
   SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

I tried to change return's indent:

---

### Convert some columns to numeric values

```
for column in cols:
    auto[column] = pd.to_numeric(auto[column])
return auto

auto = read_auto_data()
```

---

2. error 2:
   TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    in ()
     1 ## Convert some columns to numeric values
     2 for column in cols:
   ----> 3     auto[column] = pd.to_numeric(auto[column])
     4 return auto
     5

TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable

Can anyone help me understand what went wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Please use four spaces indenting to get code as-is. Your formatting is impossible to read, and in Python indenting is important.

Comment: Also, are you trying to use a list comprehension? Or is this inside of some function definition? List comprehensions don't use the `return` statement.

Comment: how can i show the indent here? when i copied my code, there are indents, but when i save, the indents are gone. Just now i also tried to edit, i checked out in the 'advanced help', seems like use '-'  should mean indent 4, '*' should mean indent 8, i add these in my code, still not showing the indent.

Comment: If you indent four spaces, you get the code environment. All further indenting inside that will be preserved. Every line of code should start with four spaces.

Comment: Yeah, finally the indents showing here. Can u take a look now?

Comment: You're not defining a function, so far as I can see. Therefore, you should not be using a `return` statement. Maybe you need a `def read_auto_data(auto):` line above the `for` line? Then indent properly to make the `for` loop and `return` statement inside the function.

Comment: What kind of object is `auto`? Can you run `type(auto)` and tell us what it returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this (the function also needs to know what `cols` is - perhaps pass that in as another parameter?):

```
def read_auto_data(auto):
    for column in cols:
        auto[column] = pd.to_numeric(auto[column])
    return auto

auto = read_auto_data()
```

Comment: Let me try, i will let u know if it works or not ASAP.

Comment: i just tried, it is true, when i put the function together, it works. I previously have defined the function already, but the indent might get messed up since there is a lot of code in between. thank you very much

Comment: You're very welcome! Glad I could be of help.